# Ambiguous foreign key in self-referencing table [SQLAlchemy/Alembic]

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have a model classes defined like this. The idea is that that `Person` will hold general information about people as well as reference to it's "sub-classes": Woman and Men as parents. Woman and Men will hold information specific for that gender.

I'm using Alembic to generate the migration but I'm getting an error:

**sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Can't determine join between 'person' and 'woman'; tables have more than one foreign key constraint relationship between them. Please specify the 'onclause' of this join explicitly.**

Note that Woman inherits from Person and therefore there is also the reference from woman to person.

Nothing I tried works:

- Remove line `mother = relationship('Woman')` with the idea that SQL alchemy doesn't understand that relationship
- Adding `mother_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('woman.id'), nullable=True)`
- Adding `mother = relationship('Woman', primaryjoin='Person.mother_id==Mother.id')`
- Specifying onclause isn't possible (or I don't know how) since the join is auto-generated

  ```
  class Person(Base):
      __tablename__ = 'person'

      id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
      gender = Column(String(5))
      name = Column(String(32), nullable=False)
      surname = Column(String(32), nullable=False)
      age = Column(Float, primary_key=True)

      mother_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('woman.id'), nullable=True)
      mother = relationship('Woman')

      _mapper_args__ = {
          'polymorphic_on': gender
      }


  class Woman(Person):
      __tablename__ = 'woman'
      __mapper_args__ = {
          'polymorphic_identity': 'woman'
      }

      id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('person.id'), primary_key=True)
  ```

Full Trace:

```
$ alembic revision --autogenerate -m "mother"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/alembic", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/alembic/config.py", line 479, in main
    CommandLine(prog=prog).main(argv=argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/alembic/config.py", line 473, in main
    self.run_cmd(cfg, options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/alembic/config.py", line 456, in run_cmd
    **dict((k, getattr(options, k)) for k in kwarg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/alembic/command.py", line 117, in revision
    script_directory.run_env()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/alembic/script/base.py", line 416, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, 'env.py')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/alembic/util/pyfiles.py", line 93, in load_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/alembic/util/compat.py", line 68, in load_module_py
    module_id, path).load_module(module_id)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 539, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1614, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 596, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1220, in load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "migrations/env.py", line 24, in <module>
    import api.model
  File "/Users/jakubt/Projects/hex/api/model.py", line 31, in <module>
    class Woman(Person):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/api.py", line 64, in __init__
    _as_declarative(cls, classname, cls.__dict__)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 88, in _as_declarative
    _MapperConfig.setup_mapping(cls, classname, dict_)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 103, in setup_mapping
    cfg_cls(cls_, classname, dict_)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 135, in __init__
    self._early_mapping()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 138, in _early_mapping
    self.map()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 530, in map
    **self.mapper_args
  File "<string>", line 2, in mapper
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 671, in __init__
    self._configure_inheritance()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 978, in _configure_inheritance
    self.local_table)
  File "<string>", line 2, in join_condition
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 965, in _join_condition
    a, b, constraints, consider_as_foreign_keys)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 1055, in _joincond_trim_constraints
    "join explicitly." % (a.description, b.description))
sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Can't determine join between 'person' and 'woman'; tables have more than one foreign key constraint relationship between them. Please specify the 'onclause' of this join explicitly.
```

Answer (score 0):

What I see as issue here is that you are referencing foreign key to foreign key.

```
mother_id -> foreign_key(woman.id)
woman.id -> foreign_key(person.id)
```

And you create circular dependancy. You cannot create that dependency in any single creation statement in any SQL dialect. You'll first need to create `person` table, then `woman` table, then add `foreign key (mother_id)` from first to second table (*note that you cannot create women table first as it has foreign key to person table*).

I don't think alembic is smart enough to do this, and I think that what you want to achieve is not good thing to do.

Here is what I suggest:

`woman.id` will always have same value for one record as `person.id`, so first foreign key should reference to person table instead of mother table.

Change definition of `mother_id` and `mother`:

```
mother_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('person.id'), nullable=True)
mother = relationship('Person', primaryjoin='Person.mother_id==Person.id')
```

**Tip:** you don't need second table if you're storing just id (just remove `__tablename__` from second class)

And check in code for gender when adding mother/father.

Comment: Thanks, this is my plan B. I also tried creating the tables in sequence - first create the table person, then the sub-table woman as a child table and then adding the constrain, it also didn't work.

I truncated the woman table for this example. It contains lot of columns.